# Use ViewModel to post into model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have one model and two viewmodels

Model:

```
 public class WebPages
{
    [Key]
    public int WebPagesId { get; set; }
    public String DomainName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DomainStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime DomainExp { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class WebPagesViewModel
{
    public String DomainName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DomainStart { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> DurationDays { set; get; }
    public int SelectedDurationDays { set; get; }
}
```

So controller for these is:

```
 //Get controller

 public ActionResult Create(WebPages model)
    {

        var vm = new WebPagesViewModel
        {
            DurationDays = new List<SelectListItem>()

            {
                new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "1 año"},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "2 años"}
                }};
                  retrun View(vm);
}

//Post controller
 public async Task<ActionResult> Create(WebPagesViewModel model)
    {
  var endDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(model.SelectedDurationDays);
        var webnew = new WebPages
        {
            DomainName = model.DomainName,
            DomainStart = model.DomainStart,
            DomainExp = endDate
        };
   db.WebPagesList.Add(webnew);
        db.SaveChanges();  
      return View(model);
```

THIS WORKS OK, I DONT HAVE ANY PROBLEMS, THAT I WANT TO DO IS ADD NEW DAYS TO Existing `DomainExp`of  specific  `DomainName` my database.

I try to do it, creating another ViewModel and create View like these:

```
 public class RenewalViewModel
{

    public int SelectedDurationDays { set; get; }
    public List<SelectListItem> AddTime { get; set; }
    public int SelectedWebPage { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Webpage { get; set; }
}
 }
```

Controllers:

```
 [HttpGet]
   public async Task<ActionResult> Renewal()
   {
       var vm = new RenewalViewModel
       {
           AddTime = new List<SelectListItem>

           {
               new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "1 año"},
               new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "2 años"},
               new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "3 años"},
               new SelectListItem {Value = "4", Text = "4 años"},
               new SelectListItem {Value = "5", Text = "5 años"},
               new SelectListItem {Value = "6", Text = "6 años"},
               new SelectListItem {Value = "7", Text = "7 años"},
               new SelectListItem {Value = "8", Text = "8 años"},
               new SelectListItem {Value = "9", Text = "9 años"}
           },
           Webpage = new SelectList(db.WebPagesList,"WebPagesId", "DomainName")
       };
        return View(vm);

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Renewal(RenewalViewModel vm)
    {

        var addDays = DateTime.Now.AddYears(vm.SelectedDurationDays);

        var webpage = new WebPages
        {
          DomainExp = addDays
        };
        db.Entry(webpage).State = EntityState.Modified;

        return View(webpage);
    }
```

But in `return View(webpage);` I have this issue

> xxx Models.Webpages is not assignable to model type xxx.Models.ViewModel.RenewalViewModel

I know this is because I called in my view RenewalViewmodel and not Webpages, I want to know what is my wrong step to do that I want

Comment: The model in the view is `@model RenewalViewModel` so you need to return a `RenewalViewModel`, not a  `WebPages` model - i.e. `return View(vm);`

Comment: but in this case how can I  compare  `DomainExp = addDays` if `DomainExp` is into `WebPages` model

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment - no where in your `Renewal` methods or associated view model is there any reference to any existing `WebPages` - all you doing is creating and saving a new `WebPages`.

Comment: Then you need to get the existing `WebPages` from the database and update its `DomainExp` value and save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because your view has `@model RenewalViewModel` but your passing an instance of `WebPages` to it. To resolve the error you need to modify the return statement to

```
return View(vm);
```

However this will then just lead to more errors because your collections for both `List<SelectListItem>` properties are `null`. If you want to return the view to make more selections, the correct approach is to redirect back to the GET method (i.e. the PRG pattern). If however you need to return the view because `ModelState` is invalid, then you need to re-assign the values of both the `AddTime` and `Webpage` properties.

Having said that, the code in your POST method does not make sense. All you are doing is creating a new instance of `Webpages` and saving it. If you wanting to add days to the selected `Webpages`, then you need to get it again from the database, update it and then save it. The code should be

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Renewal(RenewalViewModel vm)
{
    if (!ModelSTate.IsValid)
    {
        // Populate the SelectList's
        model.Webpage = ....
        model.AddTime = ....
        return View(vm);
    }
    // Get the data model
    WebPages model = db.WebPagesList.Where(x => x.WebPagesId == vm.SelectedWebPage).FirstOrDefault();
    if (model != null)
    {
        // Not really sure if you mean AddYears or AddDays?
        model.DomainExp = model.DomainExp.AddYears(vm.SelectedDurationDays);
        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    // Redirect
    return RedirectToAction(....);
}
```

Side note: Rather than repeating code in both the GET and POST methods, create a separate method

```
private void ConfigureRenewalViewModel(RenewalViewModel model)
{
    model.Webpage = ....
    model.AddTime = ....
}
```

and then call it in both methods before returning the view

```
ConfigureRenewalViewModel(vm);
return View(vm);
```

Comment: I see you accepted, then unaccepted. Is there something that your not understanding?

Comment: Great, can you recomend me somthing to read to create separate methods? I supposed I use `private void...` in controller and `model.Webpages` equals to `DomainName`  of webpages model

Comment: The `private void ConfigureRenewalViewModel(RenewalViewModel model)` goes in the controller and just means that instead of having to duplicate the code for creating the SelectLists in both the GET and POST (if you need to return the view) - its just in one place - ie the DRY principal. But I do not understand what you mean by _`model.Webpages` equals to `DomainName` of webpages model_

Comment: I got it!, one question, use separate method is only for best practice or it affect as speed loading or something like that?

Comment: There is no impact on performance - its best practice because you are not duplicating code (and if you have to modify it later, then you only need to modify it in one place)

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the Model and not the ViewModel. The model is for persistence and the ViewModel is for your UI. If you need the output of the operation for the UI then you'll need to add it as a property on the ViewModel.

Change

```
return View(webpage);
```

To:

```
return View(vm);
```

Or, if you don't want to return the VM:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```